# C# SelectMany error " Cannot Implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<List>' "

Tags: c#, list, linq, types, ienumerable

Inside of a linq `Select` I have a `SelectMany` which is throwing an error

> C# SelectMany error " Cannot Implicitly convert type
> '`System.Collections.Generic.List<char>`' to
> '`System.Collections.Generic.List<List>`' "

```
List<Hotel> hotelList = reservations
    .GroupBy(i => i.hotelID)
    .Select(c => new Hotel()
    {
        HotelID = c.First().HotelID,
        HotelName = c.First().HotelName,
        HotelAddress1 = c.First().HotelAddress1,
        HotelAddress2 = c.First().HotelAddress2,
        HotelAddress3 = c.First().HotelAddress3,
        HotelCity = c.First().CCCity,
        HotelPostalCode = c.First().CCZip,
        ReservationNumbers = c.SelectMany( i => i.ReservationNumber).Distinct().ToList()

    }).ToList();
```

`SelectMany` automatically converts it to a `IEnumerable<char>`, and then `ToList` turns that to `List<Char>`

`i.ReservationNumber` is of type `String`, `ReservationNumbers` is of type `List<string>`, `c` is of type `IGrouping<Reservation, int>`

What would be a way to force conversion to `List<string>` or how to make `SelectMany` to return a `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: If `ReservationNumber` is a string, then `SelectMany( i => i.ReservationNumber)` selects individual characters of that string and merges them into a single stream across all reservations. Is that what you wanted, or did you in fact mean `.Select( i => i.ReservationNumber)`?

Comment: Why `SelectMany` in the firstplace? I believe you only want `.Select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i.ReservationNumber` is of type `String`, you need to write simply

`ReservationNumbers = c.Select( i => i.ReservationNumber).Distinct().ToList()`

`SelectMany` tries to iterate through the elements of `ReservationNumber`, which, being `String`, is an `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: Yeah I think this is exactly it, I am not too sure why I thought I Need SelectMany, there's a 10-minute time limit on accepting an answer to a question so I will mark this as the right answer as soon as the time limit goes by

Comment: @FarisKapo I believe you wrote "SelectMany" because you wanted to... well, select many reservation numbers :) As a separate question, why isn't Hotel an entity in its own right? With Reservations as navigational property?

Comment: I need a list of Hotels to pass into a larger object of a Payment, in the case of one payment grouping multiple reservations at different hotels, this is just the way I made the objects. There is definitely room for further improvement in there